# Visual Basic Max File Size Error

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, file-upload, error-handling

```
Protected Sub AddFileButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
     ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  
        Dim fileSize = FileUploader.PostedFile.ContentLength
    If FileUploader.HasFile Then    
        
        Try
            Dim extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploader.FileName)
            Dim uniqueFileName = System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString() & extension
            FileUploader.SaveAs("\\path\" & FileUploader.FileName)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Info.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString()
        End Try
        
    Else
         If fileSize > 1048576 Then
            Info.Text = "This file exceeds the allowed file size (1 MB). Please resize the image or select another file."
             return
         
         ElseIf fileSize < 1 Then
            Info.Text = "This file does not have enough content to send. Please choose another file."
            return
         End If   
    End If
End Sub
```

Hey team! I have a quick question. I am trying to handle my max file size error.

It works if the file is too small. However, if the file is too big(1mb) I am getting the error

> Blockquote
> Server Error in '/' Application
>
> Maximum request length exceeded.
>
> **Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

How would I get past the error screen and just tell the user to upload a smaller file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `else` statement for the `If FileUploader.HasFile Then` doesn't make sense.  If there is no file to upload, how are you checking the file size?  Move the subnested if statements (`If fileSize > 1048576 Then`) into the primary IF statement.  Like this:

```
If FileUploader.HasFile Then    

     If fileSize > 1048576 Then
        Info.Text = "This file exceeds the allowed file size (1 MB). Please resize the image or select another file."
         return

     ElseIf fileSize < 1 Then
        Info.Text = "This file does not have enough content to send. Please choose another file."
        return
     Else
         Try
             Dim extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploader.FileName)
             Dim uniqueFileName = System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString() & extension
             FileUploader.SaveAs("\\filepath\" & FileUploader.FileName)
         Catch ex As Exception
             Info.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString()
         End Try
     End If   

End If
```